# How to re-enable JAyatana in PHPStorm 10

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-10

Jayatana has been disabled in PHPStorm 10 by the developers because it caused some bugs. How can it be re-enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit phpstorm.sh and comment everything related with Jayatana.

```
if [ -n "$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" -a "$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" != "${JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS%-javaagent*jayatanaag.jar*}" ] ; then
    export _ORIGINAL_JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="${JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS%-javaagent*jayatanaag.jar*}${JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS#*jayatanaag.jar}"
fi
```